# Can not cd into symlink on Debian 7

Tags: linux, debian, symbolic-link

I want to give user `webadmin` full access to directory `/usr/tomcat/webapps`.

So, I have created a symlink in `webadmin`'s home directory to the target directory:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 webadmin tomcat   28 Aug 19 22:32 webapps -> /usr/tomcat/webapps/
```

The problem: when logged in (via ssh) as `webadmin`, the `webapps` symlink appears as above but when I want to cd into it the response is:

```
can't cd to webapps
```

With `root` user I can `cd` from `/home/webadmin` into `webapps` symlink, so the link points to a valid location.

This is even more vexing since both `/usr/tomcat/` and `/usr/tomcat/webapps` are now set to `777`.

Comment: What are the permissions of `/usr/tomcat/`?

Comment: as said above the permissions are `777`. 
Ownership is `tomcat_user` and `tomcat_group`.

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -ld /usr/tomcat` and `ls -ld /usr/tomcat/webapps`

Comment: Sorry, I missed `/usr/tomcat/`, I thought you had only mentioned `/usr/tomcat/webapps`.

Comment: @zagrimsan  `ls -ld /usr/tomcat/` :
`drwxrwxrwx 9 tomcat_user tomcat_group 4.0K Aug 18 15:56 /usr/tomcat/`
`# ls -ld /usr/tomcat/webapps` :
`drwxrwxrwx 8 webadmin tomcat_group 4.0K Aug 19 18:16 /usr/tomcat/webapps`

Comment: Is the ssh session of `webadmin` chrooted, perhaps? If you do `ls /` while logged in as `webadmin` via ssh, do you see the expected server root or something else? How about if you log in as `webadmin` locally (if that is possible), does the symlink then work?